# Focus ring not working in D3300 with factory supplied 18 - 55 mm lens

Tags: lens, nikon, autofocus, focus, manual-focus

I have this D3300 that was working completely fine.

Someone was playing with the settings and I realized that I cannot focus on objects anymore.

I don't think that there is something physically wrong with the lens, but most probably with the settings.

When I choose MF (manual focus) from the camera's shortcut settings panel, I can see that the focus area mode is disabled when it is in MF mode. Also when AF is active, I still get very blurry images, just like if the focus mechanism is disabled or so since I can't hear the focus motor in my lens anymore.. What could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Although there are several variations of Nikon 18-55mm kit lenses, most if not all of them have an AF/MF switch on the lens as well. Have you checked the switch on the lens to see if it has been moved?

If the camera menu has AF turned off but the lens switch is set to AF you may not be able to move the focus ring on the lens. If you can move it you may be risking damage to the lens to do so when the switch is set to AF. To manually focus you need to move the AF/MF switch on the lens to MF.

Comment: 18-55 kit lens for the D3300 should either be the VR II AF-S or VR AF-P. The AF-S model (which I have) has the AF/MF toggle switch on the lens as you've described, but apparently on the AF-P it can only be changed from the camera menu. Unfortunately I don't have an AF-P lens to check how it works in normal operation.